# How to write a T-SQL query which can return 0 rows as part of a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying to write a query which checks how many records arrived in the last x days so that I can send out an alert if no new records have arrived in that window.

To that end I want a query which will check the table and return either 1 row stating no files were detected if there is a problem or no rows if everything is ok. The reason I want there to be no rows is because the downstream program will treat any returned rows as an error having been detected and alert accordingly.

```
select 'Null check' as id,
case when
count(*) > 0 then NULL
else 'No files detected' end as Message
from TABLE where LASTUPDATEDATE > dateadd(d, -1, getdate())
```

This query works if an error is detected but not in the correct case as it still returns a row. How can I rewrite it so that it doesn't return anything? Thanks!

Comment: Aside: If `LastUpdateDate` includes a time, e.g. is a `DateTime`, and you want to filter on dates, not 24-hour periods from the current time, then you should use `Cast( DateAdd( day, -1, GetDate() ) )` so that you only use the date and not time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance reasons, I would recommend writing this as:

```
select 'Null check' as id, 'No files detected' as Message
from (select top (1) t.*
      from table t
      where lastupdatedate > dateadd(day, -1, getdate())
     ) t
having count(*) = 0;
```

This saves SQL Server from actually having to count a bunch of rows if when things are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a task for NOT EXISTS:

```
select 'Null check' as id, 'No files detected' as Message
where not exists
(
  select *
  from tab
  where lastupdatedate > dateadd(day, -1, getdate())
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use `having count(*) = 0`

```
select 'Null check' as id, 'No files detected' as Message
from TABLE 
where LASTUPDATEDATE > dateadd(d, -1, getdate())
having count(*) = 0
```

**Demo**

[SQL Fiddle - count() = 0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/78199/0)
[SQL Fiddle - count() > 0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/78200/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a CASE and subquery:

```
SELECT [Message] = 
    CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [TABLE] WHERE [LASTUPDATEDATE] > DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE())), 0) > 0
        THEN 'No files detected'
        ELSE NULL
    END ;
```

Comment: This is more likely to error, due to the subquery returning multiple rows.

Comment: Edited to fix @Larnu's comment.

Comment: The OP wants "no rows if everything is ok". Your query will always return one row.